# Creating secure connection to https

Tags: android, ssl, https

I'm sending GET and POST requests to a https server, i've googled some tutorials for working with https ssl and found various outdated tutorials

So now i'd like to know if my written code is secure or it's not secured at all

```
        final URL url = new URL(inputURL);
        final HttpsURLConnection conn_get = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        SSLSocketFactory sslSocketFactory = createTrustAllSslSocketFactory();
        conn_get.setSSLSocketFactory(sslSocketFactory);
        in = new BufferedInputStream(conn_get.getInputStream());
        ...
```

and the SSLSocketFactory

```
private static SSLSocketFactory createTrustAllSslSocketFactory() throws Exception {
    TrustManager[] byPassTrustManagers = new TrustManager[]{ new X509TrustManager() {
        public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
            return new X509Certificate[0];
        }

        public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) {
        }

        public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) {
        }
    }};
    SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
    sslContext.init(null, byPassTrustManagers, new SecureRandom());
    return sslContext.getSocketFactory();
}
```

Should i change something or not for secure purposes?

Comment: Better you use bks file created with your server certificate or you can pass your certificate while you are calling the api that will give more security to your application. and trusting all the certificate is not good at all.

Comment: @SilvansSolanki i've read about this, i went over some tutorials but all of them seems to be invalid and many of them has deprecated functions, do you know where can i find anything UPDATED ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So now i'd like to know if my written code is secure or it's not secured at all

It is not secure, as you are blindly accepting all SSL certificates, even fraudulent ones. Your app [will not be allowed to ship on the Play Store](https://commonsware.com/blog/2016/02/22/about-x509trustmanager-emails.html), and in some countries [you might be sued by the government](https://www.ftc.gov/news-events/press-releases/2014/03/fandango-credit-karma-settle-ftc-charges-they-deceived-consumers).

> Should i change something

Keep these lines:

```
final URL url = new URL(inputURL);
final HttpsURLConnection conn_get = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
in = new BufferedInputStream(conn_get.getInputStream());
```

Delete everything else.

Comment: how about using BKS file or certificate while calling api?

Comment: @SilvansSolanki: There are plenty of recipes out there for actually validating a self-signed certificate. I have a canned implementation in [my `TrustManagerBuilder`](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-security/blob/master/TrustManagerBuilder.markdown).

Comment: @CommonsWare without ssl host refuses to send me a respond, instead im getting handshake exception, I just used your api and it's working! thank you

Comment: @CommonsWare guess i've mismatched something, using the .useDefault method doesnt work, so how do i configure the builder to work with my host?

Comment: @user3544092: You have not explained what your symptoms are, either in your question or your comments. Also, you have not explained what it is that you are actually trying to do. Hence, I do not know what to tell you. If you are trying to use a self-signed certificate, [there are instructions for that](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-security/blob/master/TrustManagerBuilder.markdown#you-want-to-use-a-self-signed-certificate).

Comment: @CommonsWare my app throws error when trying to connect the host `javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException` on the line `conn_get.getInputStream()`, I just want my app to accept the server's certification so i can do get and post requests... should i still use a selfsigned file for this operation?

Comment: @user3544092: If the server is using a self-signed certificate, you need to use a self-signed certificate. If the server is using a traditional SSL certificate, backed by some root authority, then either the server is mis-configured or the root authority is not one that your version of Android recognizes.

Comment: @CommonsWare thank you for making it clear, now i could make it work after doing some more researches regarding to self-signed cert file. you api made it even more easy to use ;)